How to do Literal Equation $ax-bc=xb-ac$?
So I am doing year 9 maths, in an extension question which was about literal equations, I was stumped. It wanted me to find $x$, using factorisation
Here is the question:
$$ax-bc = xb-ac$$
Here is how far I got before being lost.
\begin{align*}ax-bc &= xb-ac\\
ax &= xb-ac+bc\\
ax &= xb+c(-a+b)\\
ax-bx &= c(-a+b)\\
x(a-b) &= c(a-b)\\
x &= c(a-b)/a-b\\
x &= c,\end{align*}
but my textbook says that the answer is actually $-c$. I am having trouble seeing how they get that. Please explain if you can. Microsoft maths solver is even more confusing because it comes up with 'extract' the minus, and it makes no sense
It says change the $(-a+b)$ to $a-b$ and EXTRACT the minus sign and put it next to $c$ to get $-c$, which makes no sense to me. I cant add an image but here is what it says
Short Solution Steps
$c(-a+b)/(a-b)$
Factor the expressions that are not already factored.
$c(-a+b)/(a-b)$
Extract the negative sign in $-a+b$.
$-с(а-b)/(a-b)$
Cancel out $a-b$ in both numerator and denominator.
$-c$
Just for confirmation. Below is how I did the question after taking info from the comments.
\begin{align*}ax-bc &= xb-ac\\
ax-bc-xb &= -ac\\
ax-bx &= -ac+bc\\
x(a-b) &= c(-a+b)\\
x(a-b) &= -c(a-b)\\
x &= -c(a-b)/a-b\\
x &= -c\\\end{align*}

Hint: verify that indeed $a - b = -(b-a)$ - i.e., switching the order of subtraction costs a minus sign.

If short solution steps make no sense, what about proof of $a-b=-(b-a)$ from axioms?

Note that $m=-(-m)$ so $a-b=-(-(a-b))=-(-a+b)=-(b-a)$.

You can't do $-a+b=a-b$. Actually $-a+b=-(a-b)$.

All of you who replied above, thankyou, I didn't understand the concept of simplifying c(-a+b). I understand what you're trying to say. Thankyou so much, you guys made my day.

In the fourth step, how did you magically convert c(-a+b) into c(a-b) those are completely different. Expanding the former gives -ac+bc while the latter gives ac-bc [I believe this is causing the trouble with the sign]
I think the solution looks something like this:
$ax - bc = xb - ac$
$ax-bx+ac-bc = 0$ [Shifting all terms to LHS]
$x(a-b) + c(a-b) = 0$ [Taking x and c common]
$(a-b)(x+c) = 0$
$x+c = 0$ [Sending (a-b) to RHS]
$x = -c$
P.S.- I have solved this on a used notepad in about a minute so, please check for errors before moving further.

See, I will just teach you the property and you try the question on your own okay?
Consider,
$$c(-a+b)=a-b$$
Now multiplying both LHS and RHS with $-1$
$$-c(-a+b)=-(a-b)$$
Now bringing the $-$ which is near the $c$ inside the bracket in LHS
$$[-(-a+b) \Rightarrow -(-a)+-(b)=a-b]$$
$$c(a-b)=-(a-b)$$
$\therefore c=-1$
This is the concept now try the question you gave yourself.
The thing you told you can't understand is the inverse of this property.
The mistake you did in your method:

From the 3rd step to 4th you converted $(-a+b)$ to $(a-b)$ instead of $(b-a)$


For answer you can refer the answer given by @CosmicFlaw
